# Data printing to wrong row

Tags: vba, excel

Ok, this the code is supposed to loop through cells in a column, update information on the row if a match is found or print to a new row if no match is found. The loop is working when it looks for a match but it prints the data off on the wrong row. For example, my rowcount will be 3 and the code is written to print on .cells(rowcount,"J") but it is printing on the 5th row on the worksheet. I don't know why it's doing that?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Set Wb1 = ThisWorkbook

'Names variable
With Wb1.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Var1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("d1")
End With

'Opens master workbook
Set WB2 = Workbooks.Open (...filepath)

WB2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a2").Select
    RowCount = 2
    Var2 = WB2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowCount, "A")

Do While Not WB2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowCount, "a") = ""
    If Var1 <> Var2 Then
        RowCount = RowCount + 1
        Var2 = WB2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowCount, "A")

    ElseIf IncNum = Var2 Then
        With WB2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowCount, "A")
        .Cells(RowCount, "a") = Var1
    End With

    ElseIf IsEmpty(Cells(RowCount, "a")) Then
        With WB2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowCount, "A")
        .Cells(RowCount, "a") = Var1
    End With

    End If
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Try stepping through your code in the VBA editor with F8 and watch the value of `RowCount` by hovering your arrow over it - your code is probably not doing what you're expecting it to.

Comment: When I hover over it, rowcount = 3. Not sure why it prints on row 5 on the excel doc.

Comment: Which line is the code stopped on when `rowcount = 3`?  Is it the line that's printing the value you're concerned about?

Comment: The code doesn't stop. It goes all the way through. The problem is when it prints the data to WB2 its not on the right row. Instead of printing to whatever row is indicated by the row count, it prints on a different row. So if rowcount= 3 it prints on row 5 in the excel doc.

Comment: @MsAgentM It probably goes through 3 iterations where `Var1 <> Var2`, then when `IncNum` is finally equal to `Var2` it prints to the row.

Comment: @MsAgentM if you use F8 (instead of F5 or pressing the "play" button) then the code will run one line at a time. I see several lines that could be printing to a cell, which one are you referring to in this case?

Comment: @MsAgentM Without seeing a sample of your data it's impossible to know exactly what's going on, but it most likely has something to with your `RowCount = RowCount + 1` being in the wrong place. Note that `RowCount` does not increase if `var1 = var2`

Comment: I have been pressing F8. I don't see the code going through multiple iterations and counting higher than I think. Again, the row count equals what I want it too and I what the row count to be the row the data prints to in the document. If row count equals 3, it prints on row 5 for some reason. If rowcount = 2, the data prints on the 3rd row.

Comment: The line that should be printing onto a cell is whatever the variable is and it does. It just prints on the wrong row. The only time I need the row count to increase is if var1 <> var2 since it prints if the other conditions are met.

Comment: Basically, is there any reason why what ever the row count is would not print to that row in the excel doc. That's what's going on here. If rowcount = 3, then I need it to print to the 3rd row on the excel doc. So if .cells(rowcount, "a") = Var1 is the line, and rowcount= 3, my expectation is that var1 would be printed to cell A3 in excel. It's not, it's printing to cell A5. The higher the rowcount, the bigger the difference. IE, rowcount=2, prints to row 3, rowcount=5 prints to row 9 in excel. How am I making it do that?

Answer (score 2):

This is nonsense:

```
 With WB2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowCount, "A")
    .Cells(RowCount, "a") = Var1
 End With
```

This is 100% synonymous with:

```
 WB2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowCount, "A").Cells(RowCount, "a") = Var1
```

Essentially (assuming RowCount=3) this says:

> On Sheet1 go to cell "A3" and go to that range's "A3". Which is, essentially, cell "A5"

Why? Because it's nonsense plus excel is weird. Someone else can explain that one.

Take all of this `With` stuff out of here and just do:

```
 WB2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowCount, "A").Value = Var1
```

Rinse and repeat for all the other similar code.

---

Here's a rewrite:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Set Wb1 = ThisWorkbook

    'Names variable
    Var1 = Wb1.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("d1")

    'Opens master workbook
    Set WB2 = Workbooks.Open (...filepath)

    RowCount = 2
    Var2 = WB2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowCount, "A")

    Do While Not WB2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowCount, "a") = ""
        If Var1 <> Var2 Then
            RowCount = RowCount + 1
            Var2 = WB2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowCount, "A")
        ElseIf IncNum = Var2 Then
            WB2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowCount, "A").Value = Var1
        ElseIf IsEmpty(Cells(RowCount, "a")) Then
            With WB2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowCount, "A").Value = Var1
        End If
    Loop

End Sub
```

---

Some tips:

Don't `.Select` a range. Especially if you aren't going to use `Selection.<something>` on the next line. There's nothing good that comes from selecting a range in VBA.

`With` is useful, but only if you plan to do more than a couple of things with it's child objects or methods like:

```
With Sheet1
    .Unprotect
    .Range("A1").Value = "Hi"
    .Range("B1").Interior.ColorIndex = 5
    .Protect "theyllneverguessthisone"
End With
```

It's superfluous if you just have a single line after it:

```
With Sheet1
    .Range("A1").Value = "Hi"
End With
```

Since that can just be rewritten as:

```
Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = "Hi"
```

Which is a lot more readable and doesn't obfuscate the intent of the code (leading to issues like you were seeing in your question).

Comment: What do you mean it's nonsense?

Comment: It's nonsense because you do `Worksheetes("Sheet1").Cells(RowCount, "A")` Which is PERFECT! You are addressing the cell you want to address and you can set its value like `Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowCount, "A").Value = Var1` Done. But... what you are doing is: `Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowCount, "A").Cells(RowCount, "A")` which is the nonsense. You are getting the "Cells" property of the cell you are already wanting. You are essentially Offsetting from "A3" 2 more rows (3 = Itself, plus 2 more) landing you on cell "A5" where you set the value.

Comment: I made those changes, rowcount= 2 but data printed on row 3 on excel doc.

Comment: I would assume because right before you print in that first `IF` condition you `RowCount = RowCount + 1`. Is that what you want to do before printing to that row?

Comment: This is where stepping through your code and looking at the values will really help.

Comment: Also, all my code is not above. Only the code with the first variable so there wouldn't be so much to sift through.

Comment: Also, I am stepping through my code. I really really promise I am. How am I offsetting without using an offset function? And yes, I do what to add to rowcount in that first if condition because I want to change Var2 to whatever is in the next cell.

Comment: I had to play around with where my rowcount was and the code is printing properly now. I still don't understand why the data didn't print on the row indicated by the rowcount. I have used that code in other projects have had had no issues. I'm going to issue the offset JNevill said I was doing since this is likely my problem. I just don't really understand the explanation left, like you said, excel is weird.